# Is there a ways I can insert large amount of rows faster into my table in Supabase?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

This query I made is working, but it's kind of slow, the last time I insert it was over 30,000 records and I have to wait for about an hour or two I guess. And it's a little bit weird that I'm using `ReactJS`, a front-end to `POST` into database, but it's working so I have no complaints about it...

But I have deleted that table and created a new one, but this time I have over 50,000 records due to updating some stuff.

This is how my table works in the Supabase

| id | anime_title | anime_episode | anime_video | anime_video |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Movie name A | Episode 1 | URL-movieA-1 | *NULL* |
| 2 | Movie name A | Episode 2 | URL-movieA-2 | *NULL* |
| 3 | Movie name A | Episode 3 | URL-movieA-3 | *NULL* |
| 4 | Movie name B | Episode 1 | URL-movieB-1 | *NULL* |
| 5 | Movie name B | Episode 2 | URL-movieB-2 | *NULL* |
| 6 | Movie name B | Episode 3 | URL-movieB-3 | *NULL* |
| 7 | Movie name C | Episode 1 | URL-movieC-1 | *NULL* |
| 8 | Movie name C | Episode 2 | URL-movieC-2 | *NULL* |
| 9 | Movie name C | Episode 3 | URL-movieC-3 | *NULL* |

So the `anime_title` is a foreign key to another table, 1 `anime_title` can contain many `anime_episode`, the `anime_video` is `null`, and please don't bother it, it use to fill data later on and I've success with it.

My problem is that with over 50,000 records, the insert will take very long. But I'm not too familiar with how to work with databases so my way seems... a bit "simple".

How does my code function: It selects `anime_title`, `anime_url`, `anime_episode` to see if it's matched in my supabase database or not, if the `data.length === 0` means it's empty in my database, I'll proceed to INSERT into it, if it's not I'll just skip it. But the larger the database, the query proceed longer and longer.

Here's my code:

```
import './index.css'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { supabase } from './supabaseClient'
import animeData from './data.json'
import animeDataEpisode from './dataEpisode.json'

export default function App() {

useEffect(async () => {
// POST Anime Episode Based on Anime Title

for(let i = 0; i < animeDataEpisode.length; i++){
  const {data, error} = await supabase
  .from('anime_detail')
  .select('anime_title, anime_url, anime_episode')
  .match({
    anime_title: animeDataEpisode[i].animeTitle, 
    anime_url: animeDataEpisode[i].animeEpisodeUrl, 
    anime_episode: animeDataEpisode[i].animeEpisode
  })

  if(data.length === 0){
    await supabase
    .from('anime_detail')
    .insert([{
      anime_title: animeDataEpisode[i].animeTitle,
      anime_url: animeDataEpisode[i].animeEpisodeUrl, 
      anime_episode: animeDataEpisode[i].animeEpisode
    }])
  }
  else(
    console.log("Record already exist, no INSERT")
  )
}
},[])

  return (
    <div className="container">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This here is exactly why you need an API between your frontend and your DB.

Comment: Is this a production app or just a tutorial? If it's a production app just stop what you're doing. You're giving full access to the db to anyone who uses the website

Comment: Do you mean it'll act like a middleware? Supabase for me it's kind of new, I haven't work with it before, so I don't exactly know what I'm doing, too. I only found a way to connect it using `React`

Comment: This feel like a model for me so I'm not planned on using it on production, I just use it to POST data from behind the scene. I have another project to just only pull data from Supabase into my `Front-end`

Comment: If you use authentication correctly with Supabase that's fine, you can use it on production. Just be careful. Let me investigate Supabase api for a while and I'll get back to you

Comment: Maybe you should go with the REST api instead of the supabase client. See more here: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/511#discussioncomment-277547

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it.

Answer (score 1):

Others are already pointing out that your current approach is pretty odd, so I will just assume you have your reasons for doing it this way and answer accordingly:

The issue you are having is that populating your database with 30,000 - 50,000 records is taking too long.

That many records sounds like an initialization load of lots of data, and doesn't sound like something you need to do often.

So you are trying to optimize how the time it takes to populate you database with the initial dataset.

Here are some things you might consider for optimizing:

Clean your data to remove duplicates before inserting. Data cleaning is a good idea anyway -- this step lets you get a good sense of the overall nature of your data, and gives you the chance to remove (potentially) unwanted stuff like nulls and duplicates. To clean your data, I personally would open it up using python and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html), they are very easy to work with for this basic data inspection and cleaning steps.

Comment out the lookup / comparison section of your useEffect code. Since you cleaned your data, you will not have any duplicates.

If you don't want to clean your data to remove duplicates and would rather keep the match-checking code, then I'd suggest looking for bottlenecks in your code. From what I can tell inserting a lot of data should NOT be taking hours. That suggests a bottleneck to me.

I'm not sure how you have your data structured, but here's an example of a significant improvement:

When you try and match an episode against an existing one in your database, it might doing a range query against every episode in your DB and checking the fields each time. That's a really bad scaling thing since you need to check N existing records each time and N is growing.

Instead, you should be able to do a hash-based equality lookup in constant time since you are just trying to find an exact match. Without knowing how supabase works under the hood it's hard for me to recommend where to start with this but perhaps you can try using the [`is` filter](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/is) over the `match` filter to try and force a much more efficient equality search.

Comment: Thank you for your tips and for which direction I need to improve, I'm very new to Supabase as well, so my approach seems very basic and very unoptimized. It's just that I store records in my JSON and it's very large. Whenever I write anything new into that JSON file, I have to hook it as an `animeDataEpisode` as you can see in my code. So, because it's large, I have to loop a whole data set of it with `SELECT`, `MATCH` that `Supabase` provide to avoid duplicate existence records and workaround it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're saying about the constraints of your data. When you being the process of uploading your JSON data to your Database, it is no longer just a big mess of raw JSON but a relational data construct. Supabase is likely doing a lot of work for you under the hood. You should still be able to do an exact match query using `is` instead of a range query.